# Установка PUG (npmjs заблокирован)

Tags: node.js, pug

Пытаюсь установить PUG. 
При установке получаю ошибку npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable: npm@latest

Лог:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 
>     1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
>     1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
>     1 verbose cli   'install',
>     1 verbose cli   'npm',
>     1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
>     2 info using npm@5.6.0
>     3 info using node@v8.11.3
>     4 verbose npm-session 165f8e808a3c6542
>     5 silly install loadCurrentTree
>     6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
>     7 http fetch GET 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 70142ms attempt #3
>     8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest 503 Service Unavailable: npm@latest
>     9 verbose stack Error: 503 Service Unavailable: npm@latest
>     9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
>     9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>     9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>     9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>     9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>     9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>     9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
>     9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
>     9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>     9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>     9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>     9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
>     10 verbose cwd C:\Users\...\Desktop
>     11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
>     12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm" "-g"
>     13 verbose node v8.11.3
>     14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
>     15 error code E503
>     16 error 503 Service Unavailable: npm@latest
>     17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Если я правильно разобрался, проблема в том, что npmjs.org заблокирован РКН. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли мое предположение и как решить проблему?

Comment: Это же легко проверить, воспользуйтесь VPN-ом